# Woocommerce "My account" page translation

Tags: woocommerce

Does anyone know how to translate this particular thing on My account page in Woocommerce? That's almost the only thing I can't find anywhere with Loco Translate

**Here's a picture of it**

[image]

Comment: Right Click And Use Translate to English.

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more clear. I'm trying to translate to my native language. The "MY ACCOUNT" marked red is nowhere to be found.

Comment: Go to: Dashboard > Settings > General and change the Site language.

Comment: It's already set to my native language. That's what's allowing me to translate using Loco translator. The MY ACCOUNT stays in English no matter what I do since it looks like it's just a text on the page, but there's no way to edit [woocommerce_my_account] page

Comment: Sorry You have to add the plugins for  that

Comment: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-localization/  .. Check This

Comment: I did. That's why I'm using Loco Translate. As you can see, most of the page is translated, but that "MY ACCOUNT" can't be found anywhere

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. The text was just a print of the page title which was still in English. When I changed the page title, the text changed as well